# Travis build for mocha-phantomjs test is failing

Tags: node.js, http, https, travis-ci, mocha-phantomjs

I am testing a API using mocha-phantomjs test. Tests are passing when i try to run it from my system but when i try to do it on Travis CI it says permission denied could not figure out how to process for that.

Build link is

https://travis-ci.org/CloudBoost/JavaScriptSDK/builds/62706200

the problem is coming because i am using a secure version of Http if i run the test using simple http it kind of works with Travis but fails with https

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your problem and I think I found the problem.

It looks like Travis CI does not like that your project has the node modules already committed in the Git repository.

So what I did is I deleted the `node_modules` directory and committed the changes.

As you can see, I could get your unit tests to run with `mocha-phantomjs`:

[Travis CI build log](https://travis-ci.org/cotsog/JavaScriptSDK/jobs/62871922)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, had the Git Hub repository without node modules earlier but was getting the same ssl handshake error which you have got.. will dig deeper and see if i can sort it out

Answer (score 0):

You are fighting again this bug:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12181

I had the same problem. On my machine (OS X) all tests pass.
But with TravisCI, it failing silently.

You can see this, wenn you attach this to casper/phantom

    `page.onResourceError = function (e) {
        console.log("Page resource failed to load. Reason: "+e.errorString);
    }`

There are a lot of parameters for ignoring the errors, but with some SSL Certs (AWS S3 for example) it's just not working. Use slimerjs instead.

https://travis-ci.org/christianhaller/travis/builds/91491853